# Nmap scanning computers behind a wireless modem

Tags: network-scanners, nmap

Let's suppose that I have a router and three computers connected to Internet through that router.  When I tried to get the external IP address for each computer, I got the same address.  I think this is due to NAT translation.  I want to know how a hacker can scan a specific computer of the three computers using nmap and get all information about that specific one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the most part, you can't.  NAT acts somewhat like a firewall with a "default deny" rule.  Unless you set up a DMZ or port forwarding, a computer on the "internet" side of the router cannot make unsolicited contact with the computers on the "private" side.

Comment: Yeah, i mean if behind a router there is a host based on windows 7 and other host based on windows 8. How can i scan only the host based on windows 7 ?

Comment: As I said in my answer, you can't.  The router prevents it.

Comment: Okay, but i wanna know how people can compromise a system if they can't scan it ?

Comment: To greatly oversimplify, by making guesses about the nature of the system.

Comment: To be a bit of a pedant, NAT doesn't provide any security by itself and could leak internal addresses.  See David's excellent answer to a similar question here:  http://security.stackexchange.com/a/8773/47496

Answer (score 0):

I'm a noob at infosec but can't you do:

`nmap 192.168.1.0/24`

This assumes you are behind the router

Comment: No, because to do that, you would have to be on that network.  The question (which may not be entirely clear) is asking how an external attacker who *isn't* on that network would target a specific computer.